# What is this dance?

Tags: negima

[image]

This is from a flash animation of Asuna (from Negima), but I've seen this in a lot of shows, especially during the ending themes. Most recently, the ED of [Recorder and Randsell Mi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TumRG0Co77I#t=2:45).

Is this a real dance or just something that's easy to animate?

Comment: Isn't that the cha cha cha?

Comment: I dunno, I guess it could be [one of the dance moves](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWrZXehnkAg), but looking through a couple of videos, I don't see them doing that.

Comment: For what it's worth, this gif is just taken from the ending to Negima!?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No, she's staying in place. Chacha involves side-stepping, she's not doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The instruments are called [Maracas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maraca) which are similar to shaker. Similar to how some singers use tambourines, other use maracas when they are singing often dancing while playing in rhythm to the shake.

You can often see backing vocalists use such instruments to appear busy when they are not required.

Here's [how to dance with Maracas](http://www.ehow.com/how_8578637_dance-maracas.html).

Comment: I've seen this without any instruments (e.g. the Recorder and Randsell MI ED)